# skins by unlocking cases CSGO

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I am playing this game from couple of months and its really cool.
I got many case drops like Operation Wildfire Case, Shadow Cases , Gamma Cases, Chrome 2 cases etc. So to get skins is it worth to spend money for unlocking those cases ??
     How many Skins would i get by unlocking those cases ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get only **1** skin per weapon case. It's one of the items in the description.

Example:

[image: enclave case]

Check the [Steam Market](http://steamcommunity.com/market/) for how much the items are worth.

Generally you can say that it's an expensive hobby since the valuable items are very hard to drop.

Comment: Usually directly buying items from marketplace is cheaper.

Comment: @arda Exactly. In probably 99.5% of the cases.

Comment: so what should i do with cases @h0ch5tr4355

Comment: You can also sell them in the market.

Comment: @rohillasarthak Open, sell or keep. Opening is likely to cause you to lose money. Selling will get you a few cents (some new cases cost more in first weeks though). Keeping will not cost you anything.